# ¿Como poner un WaterMark o marca de agua a mis productos sin stock woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Buen dia, necesito poner una imagen como marca de agua a mis productos que no tienen stock en mi tienda de `woocommerce` algún ejemplo que me sirva de guía?, encontre este ejemplo aqui mismo pero sin ningun resultado.

ADD: Actualice el código que estoy intentando aplicar para este fin pero se queda la pagina en blanco osea no me muestra nada.

```
 add_filter('woocommerce_single_product_image_html', 'marca_agua_funcion', 10, 2);
function marca_agua_funcion($loop, $product){

     if ( ! $product->is_in_stock()) {
 //Ruta de mi imagen marca de agua  
$estampa = imagecreatefrompng('http://138.197.9.71/wp-content/themes/vg-galio/images/cart-remove.png');

//Intento capturar en una variable la ruta donde guarda las imagenes woocommerce
$im = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $loop->post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );

// Establecer los márgenes para la estampa y obtener el alto/ancho de la imagen de la estampa
$margen_dcho = 10;
$margen_inf = 10;
$sx = imagesx($estampa);
$sy = imagesy($estampa);

// Copiar la imagen de la estampa sobre nuestra foto usando los índices de márgen y el
// ancho de la foto para calcular la posición de la estampa. 
imagecopy($im, $estampa, imagesx($im) - $sx - $margen_dcho, imagesy($im) - $sy - $margen_inf, 0, 0, imagesx($estampa), imagesy($estampa));

// Imprimir y liberar memoria
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
}
return $product;
}
```

Comment: Hola Guille. Por qué sin ningun resultado ?  Te deja la imagen tal cual la tenias ? te da fallos ?

Comment: Hola lois6b actualice el codigo que he estado intentando para este fin, el problema es que no se como capturar la ruta de donde se muestran las imagenes, encontre que se usa esto  `wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $loop->post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ` pero bueno no se como hacer enfin para poner una amrca de agua para los productos sin stock.